# Variable in html ,angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on an app in angular and in an html file i have something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let var of list">
  <div>
     {{newVar.name}}
   <div>
</div>
```

My problem is that i dont know how to declare newVar properly in the div because i want newVar to be a result returned from a function in the component that takes the first var as parameter

so i basically want something like

```
newVar=func(var)
```

before using the name attribute and i dont know how to do this

I could do func(var).name but i dont only display the name so i dont want to call the function multiple times

Comment: You want your function to **populate** `newVar` not for `newVar` to be your function. When you call you function depends on when you want this to get populated

Comment: i want the function to populate newvar before i display it yes

Comment: rather than looping in html, why not loop in TS and generated div for each var dynamically

Comment: it is not my code ,i am simply adding to one

Answer (score 1):

So your workaround is something like , streaming `list` in html and passing `var` to typescript function `func(var)` storing result in `newVar`. From there you want to display `name` value in UI . Is my understanding is correct , my suggestion is

ts

```
newVar = [];
///
func() {
  list.forEach(element=>{
    newVar.push(element);
  });
}
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let var of newVar">
  <div>
     {{var.name}}
   <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there aren't any direct solution for this. One workaround is to use *ngFor as a hack (and the cost is performance)

```
<div *ngFor="let _var of list">
  <div *ngFor="let newVar of [func(_var)]">
    {{newVar.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how slower it is since the list basically only has an element?

Comment: Angular will have to re-render entire that div each time `var` change (due to its change-detection mechanism), and re-rendering is costly

Comment: As a side-note, a recommend you rename `var` into something else, because `var` is a keyword of javascript/typescript

Comment: it is named something else ,it was just for example

Answer (score 0):

you has severals options:

```
<div *ngFor="let var of list">
    {{func(var).name}}
</div>
```

Use an auxiliar array

```
//in your .ts
auxArray:any[]=[];

this.auxArray=this.list.map(x=>this.func(x))

//and iterate over auxArray
    <div *ngFor="let var of auxArray">
        {{var.name}}
    </div> 

 //or iterate over list and use "index"
    <div *ngFor="let var of list;let i=index">
        {{var}} = {{auxArray[i].name}}
    </div>
```

If your list is an array of object you can also

```
//in your .ts
this.list.forEach(x=>{
   data:this.func(x)
}

//and iterate over list but use data.name
    <div *ngFor="let var of list">
        {{var.data.name}}
    </div>
```

The first option has a poor efficency because Angular execute the function several times -each time check the application, you can see if use a `console.log(var)` in your function

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables to newvar function like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let var of list">  
    <div>      {{newVar(var)}}    <div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution,basically you can do something like

```
<div *ngIf="func(var) as newVar">
   {{newVar.name}}
</div>
```